# iOS: layer (updating on CADisplayLink) added to view triggers [view layoutSubviews] 60x/sec -- Why?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, layoutsubviews

I cannot figure this out.

I have a view.

it is a speedometer.

I put a needle in the speedometer:

```
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
{    
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame]; // [super initWithCoder: coder];
    if (! self)
        return nil;

    :
    :
    : 
    self.needle = [ [ [Needle alloc] initWithMaxRadius: 0.5*300

    [self.layer addSublayer: needle.layer];

    self.needle.layer.position = CGPointMake( frame.size.width / 2, frame.size.height / 2 );

    return self;
}
```

The needle object contains a CALayer property.

the needle takes care of positioning itself for every frame -- it sets up its own display link handler and performs a transform on this layer

now suddenly my view's layoutSubviews method gets hit every frame.

I cannot understand this behaviour.

I can understand  some change in the SUPERview causing this method to get hit.
 but how can a SUBlayer force this?

surely a sublayer should be at the mercy of its parent?

I tried setting

```
self.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

which obviously has no effect

the property I'm looking for would be

```
self.getsAutoresizedBySubviewsOrLayers = NO;
```

what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a subview will cause `layoutSubviews` to be called on the subview, it's target, and all subviews of the target.

You can find more info here in the question [When is layoutSubviews called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called)

Incidentally, you might have some memory leaks in the code above.

If `needle` is a retained property, this line will cause over retention:

```
self.needle = [ [ [Needle alloc] initWithMaxRadius: 0.5*300
```

In general, it's better never to refer to "`self.`" in an init method.