# How to make a parent view autoresize based on subview for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, autoresize

I have a UIScrollView and a subview in it. I would like to swap subviews and have the scroll view automatically resize its content view to the size of the subview.

Any suggestions on how I may do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `-(void)layoutSubviews` to your class. Whenever u swap the subviews, this would get called. There you take the size of the subview and you can set the content size of the scrollview.

Not exact reference. But u can know something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called).