# why might layoutSubviews NOT automatically be called on a view when its frame is set?

Tags: iphone, uiview, frame, resize, autoresizingmask

I have a view.  It is part of a large and complex project.  When the frame of my view is set, layoutSubviews is not automatically called.

Playing around with this, I tried putting the following method into my view:

```
-(void) setFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    NSLog (@"setting frame");
    [super setFrame: frame];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

At this point, layout was redone when the frame was set, as expected.  And if I commented out the setNeedsLayout line, layout was not done.  Furthermore, when I click on "step into" at the line where super is called, the debugger does not step into anything.  So as far as I can tell, super's setFrame method is not being overridden.

FWIW, I also did a small test project in which I changed the frame of a view.  In this case, layoutSubviews was called when I did that.  [setNeedsLayout was not called in my test project.]  So something in my large project is changing the behavior.  But I don't know what that something is.

Can anyone explain what might be going on?

EDIT: to clarify, my frame change is changing the view's height.  The width is not changed.

Comment: You aren't the only one mystified.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called