# iOS app layout changed after phone call

Tags: ios, layout, resize, phone-call

If I receive a phone call while using my app, the view is bumped down a bit to make room for the call status bar at the top.

Once the call is over, the view stays in this 'altered' state. How can I force the app to re-size itself?  Currently I have to kill the app and re-start.

Comment: can you show the screent shot of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any custom views that override `-layoutSubviews`?

In my experience, this means you have a view that does custom layout using `-layoutSubviews` but does not call `-setNeedsLayout:` at the appropriate times; in general [setting the frame does not force a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921610/why-might-layoutsubviews-not-automatically-be-called-on-a-view-when-its-frame-is) (auto-layout is handled differently).

In any view that overrides `-layoutSubviews`, try the following:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  CGRect oldFrame = self.frame;

  // This check changes behaviour slightly:
  //   v.frame = v.frame;
  // no longer cancels animations.
  // Sometimes this works around an animation glitch.
  if (!CGRectEqualToRect(frame,oldFrame))
  {
    [super setFrame:frame];
    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(frame.size,oldFrame.size))
    {
      // Only layout if the size changes.
      [self setNeedsLayout];
    }
  }
}
```

(You could do the same for `-setBounds:` but it's generally unnecessary since AFAIK it doesn't get called by UIKit except for `UIScrollView`.)