# When is autoresizingMask realized?

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, lifecycle

I would like to know in which part of the application lifecycle a `UIView` is resized. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check [when-does-layoutsubviews-get-called](http://blog.logichigh.com/2011/03/16/when-does-layoutsubviews-get-called/). In addiction you can find additional info on [when-is-layoutsubviews-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called).

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Till thank you for your fix. I will remember the right layout for links.