# why isn't -layoutSubviews being called?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, layoutsubviews

I'm trying to create a custom layout for some subviews. My file is a `ViewController`, so I have to refer to its view as `self.view`. The subviews are subviews of `self.view`.

When I call `[self layoutSubviews];` explicitly in `viewDidLoad`, it will execute the code in `-layoutSubviews` without a problem.

However, I've read that I shouldn't call `-layoutSubviews` explicitly, or call it on `self` since that's a `UIViewController`. I tried implementing `-setNeedsLayout` by calling it like this: `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` in `viewDidLoad`, and taking out the explicit call of `-layoutSubviews` but keeping its declaration. But that didn't seem to work.

I was linked to [an article about when layoutSubviews is called](http://blog.logichigh.com/2011/03/16/when-does-layoutsubviews-get-called/) and it seems like it should be called when I add subviews, but that doesn't seem to be happening here.

If I want to be safe, and do things the way it suggests in the class reference for `UIView` and its methods, how should I go about being able to use both methods?

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as `-[UIViewController layoutSubviews]` or `-[UIViewController setNeedsLayout]`. These are `UIView` methods.

If you want to use the `layoutSubviews` system, you need to subclass your top-level `UIView` and implement it there. By default, it does nothing. If you want to layout your views using the view controller, then I would name the methods something else (like `layout`, since a view controller doesn't have "subviews") to avoid confusion with `UIView`.

Comment: Rob, I wrote a UISearchBarCustomized class which has layoutSubViews implemented. Then I put a searchbar into a xib file with class name set to UISearchBarCustomized, but the layoutSubViews doesn't get called. Then i also tried to put a UIView into the xib and then put the searchbar onto that UIView...then layoutSubViews didn't get called and also search bar is not shown on that view..do you know how to get it fixed?

Comment: You should ask this as a question. You should also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called.

Answer (score 1):

You should never call `-layoutSubviews` directly. It might be detrimental to performance, but other reasons might as well apply. Instead call `-setNeedsLayout`. This method sets a flag (or Boolean) that on some next drawing pass the `-layoutSubviews` method should be called (several methods might set this flag, but it won't force a redraw until the time is right).

Does your `-layoutSubviews` implementation call `-layoutSubviews` on the super class?

Perhaps you should show some code so we might help you further with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your layout related codes in *- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews* method and call *[self.viewControllerObject.view setNeedsLayout]* where ever you need to layout your subviews of viewControllerObject.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rob Napier answered,

> There is no such thing as -[UIViewController layoutSubviews] or -[UIViewController setNeedsLayout]. These are UIView methods.

This is nice, So we are about to subclassing the `UIView` & assign it as the custom class of the `UIViewController`'s `view` property. It will work as well, but very lengthy & too much to do for each `UIViewController`.

There is a easier way (**obvious way what we should follow**) using the [`viewWillLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) & [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) provided in the `UIViewController` class.

As the name suggested they are called just before & after, doing the layout thing in the `UIView`.

Hope these might help 
Happy coding