# When Exactly Does layoutSubviews get called for custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When exactly does `layoutSubviews` get called on a custom `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableViewCells` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? Below, I need `layoutSubviews` to be called AFTER I set the `FiltersTableViewCellItem` property. Do I have this set up correctly? I'd like to be able to use `layoutSubviews` because I heard it's better for performance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FiltersTableViewCell";
    FiltersTableViewCell *filtersTableViewCell = [[self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier] retain];
    FiltersTableViewCellItem *filtersTableViewCellItem = [[self.filtersTableViewCellItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] retain];

    if (!filtersTableViewCell)
    {
        filtersTableViewCell = [[FiltersTableViewCell alloc] initWithFiltersTableViewCellItem:filtersTableViewCellItem];
        filtersTableViewCell.delegate = self;
    }
    else
    {
        filtersTableViewCell.filtersTableViewCellItem = filtersTableViewCellItem;
    }
    return [filtersTableViewCell autorelease];
}
```

Comment: @Danny Lin ARC has nothing to do with performance improvements.  In fact it has much the same effect as autorelease.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`layoutSubviews` is called at some point after `tableView:willDisplayCell:`, which is called after `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You can verify this by setting breakpoints in the relevant methods and seeing the order in which they get hit. For example, set a breakpoint at the end of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Then add the following method to `FiltersTableViewCell`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

and set a breakpoint there. Then run the app and see what happens.

Comment: But note, even if `layoutSubviews` is called after `willDisplayCell`, that doesn't mean that's when the layout pass for sake of self-sizing is done. I'm finding that a self-sizing cell that isn't populated until `willDisplayCell` doesn't get the correct height, even if it also forces a layout pass by calling `layoutIfNeeded`. I had to change my code to populate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead for self-sizing to work.

Comment: @PierreHouston
can you tell me how i can get size of UIButton in UITableViewCell while cell is loading because I want to decrease size of UIButton height according to content. I made Custom Cell in iPhone 8. In iPhone 5 I get size of UIButton is same as iPhone 8. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try calling setNeedsLayout after setting your item.

```
filtersTableViewCell.filtersTableViewCellItem = filtersTableViewCellItem;
[filtersTableViewCell setNeedsLayout];
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330162/1247984) ,
there are many instances where it will be called. I would also say that it might be called when a reusable item is dequeued from the reusable cells queue. Try setting the FiltersTableViewCellItem before looking for reusable items.