# Who should manage the UI Elements, the view or the view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, rotation

I am currently developing an iOS app and I was wondering how to manage the UI elements. I am using a Storyboard to place my views and Autolayout to make everything resolution independent. If it helps, here's a bit of background on how I came up with this question.

### Some Backgroud

[image: Button layout]

I have buttons the represent piano keys and I later in code add a subview to these that draws the actual keys on them. I did this by creating `@IBOutlets` on the ViewController and susbscribed to the **`UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`**. This called a method that adds the subviews based on the current button `frames` to get the appropriate sized keys.

This worked fine when running in iOS 8.1, but if I ran the app on **iOS 7**, the frames of the buttons weren't updated to the new orientation by the time I got the **`UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`**, so everything was messed up in landscape. I did a little research ([UIInterfaceOrientation not yet updated when UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification caught in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974246/uiinterfaceorientation-not-yet-updated-when-uideviceorientationdidchangenotifica)) and it seems that a good solution would be to override the `layoutSubviews` method. Problem is, **`layoutSubviews`is a UIView method, and I am managing my buttons and UI in my UIViewController.**

Impulsively I wanted to subclass my UIView, override layoutSubviews and from there call a method on my Controller to add the keys to the buttons correctly, but that doesn't sound right.

### The Questions

My UI is managed by the UIViewController. But I need to update my views based on a method proper of a UIView. I assume, to respect the MVC principles, that my view should't now a thing about my controller, but then this brings up a few questions:

- Who should be managing the UI?
- Is my strategy wrong and should the
  UIView hold the `@IBOutlets` to the buttons so that it can later
  apply the subviews I need them to have?
- If you read the background, do you have a suggestion for this particular situation?

I assume the complexity of this problem is relatively small and I don't need to setup notifications in NSNotificationCenter, but I may be wrong. I would really like to hear this is not the only solution.

Thanks in advance. I hope I was clear enough, but if you want/need any additional details on my particular situation, let me know and I will gladly elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood the question correctly, your ViewController should be laying out the keys within it's view. A good, but not the only, place to do this is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which a method you can override on UIViewController.

Now if your views should maintain their internal layout. i.e if you buttons/keys have any subviews, you should update those in `layoutSubviews` on UIView as you mentioned.

Both methods will be called in response to changes in the bounds or center of your parent view.

As far as rotation changes are concerned, in iOS 8, you should use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` or `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:`
 depending on your needs.

I highly recommend that you write your layout independent of orientation. You should just use the containing view's bounds for reference and *never hard code* in any frames. For example perhaps one of your keys should be 1/56 the width of it's superview instead of a magical number for portrait and  landscape.

Comment: Oh, this makes a lot of sense. One question though, what view should override `layoutSubviews` to update the internal layout? The buttons? But I read that I shouldn't subclass UI elements. Or in a subclass of the view that contains the buttons, but then I would need to have `@IBOutlets` on this UIView subclass, since I need to know which key is which and I specified that in the Storyboard. And thanks for the other recommendations, I will definitely make good use of them :)

Comment: Subclassing UIButton is tricky! I would just encapsulate the button in a custom view and do the custom layout there. If thats overkill you can just do the layout in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in the ViewController. Just use your best judgement on what you think makes the most sense and what seems like the clearest way to proceed.