# View Position Resets with bringSubviewToFront [AutoLayout]

Tags: objective-c, swift

Using Autolayout, everytime I call `bringSubviewToFront`, the UIView resets.

I tried setting an original position with `txtViewPosition`:

```
        txtViewPosition = CGRect(x: txtView.frame.origin.x, y: txtView.frame.origin.y, width: txtView.frame.size.width, height: txtView.frame.size.height)
        containerView.bringSubviewToFront(txtView)
        txtView.frame = txtViewPosition!
```

It looks like the view is the correct position, but it is still showing up in its original spot (set in AutoLayout).

#### Update (UIView still snaps back)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if txtViewPosition != nil {
        println("txt position is \(txtViewPosition)")
        txtView.frame = txtViewPosition!
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how you adjust the frame, auto layout will reset the frame on the next `-layoutSubviews`. See [When is layoutSubviews called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called) for an explanation of when this happens (note: `-setFrame:` and `bringSubviewToFront` cause it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have finer grain control over the layout then you need to makes the changes in [`-layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) or [`-viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews).

Comment: So I need to edit the layoutSubviews each time i call `bringSubviewToFront`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. To clarify, `-layoutSubviews` and `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` are called each and every time a view changes its layout. These callbacks are where you should set your frames.

Comment: I decided to make the change: `txtView.frame = txtViewPosition!` in `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` since it's called after `-layoutSubviews`. However, the view still snaps back to the original location.

Answer (score 0):

Both **view.bringSubviewToFront(txtView)** and **view.sendSubviewToBack(txtView)** reset view position if you animate the view position instead of the constraints. You can use **txtView.layer.zPosition** instead. The default value is 0. Giving a higher number will bring the view to front.