# Adding Images By incrementing label count

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uilabel

Here,when button taps label count is increments & decrements.While label count increments images will be added by respective count.here my code for incrementing label count

```
if (counter >= 9 )
    return;
[_count setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++counter]];
```

but i need to display while incrementing the label count then automatically increments images one by one.like this

[image]

Can you please help me how can i implement,thank you.

Comment: maybe you will keep all men in one image and just change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `UIScrollView` in place of where you want to show images. When click on '+' button, call following method by passing the 'counter' value.

```
-(void)addImage:(int) count {
  UIScrollView * scView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
  scView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 60, self.view.frame.size.width, 60);
  UIButton * btn;
  UIImageView * imgV;
  float imgWidth = 44;
  for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgV.frame = CGRectMake(i*imgWidth, 0, imgWidth, 44);
    imgV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gitar"];
    [scView addSubview:imgV];
  }
  [scView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imgWidth*count, 50)];
  [scView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  [self.view addSubview:scView];
}

- (IBAction)descrese:(id)sender {
   counter -= 1;
   [self addImage:counter];
}

- (IBAction)btnTap:(id)sender {
    counter += 1;
    [self addImage:counter];
}
```

This adds as many images as you want in horizontal scroll view.

Comment: Thank you @Bharath it's working,and for decrement of images how can i implement

Comment: for(scView in [scView subviews]) {
        [imgV removeFromSuperview];
    }

Comment: @iOS2340 Simply pass your counter value to above method all the times either decrement or increment, it will add those many images in scrollview.

Comment: I tested its working fine for me. I'm 2 more methods in my answer , one for decrement image count and other is for increment image count. hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

use a uiscrollview with cells of images, that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIScrollView.
As number of elements is increasing/decreasing:
1) increse/deacrease UIScrollView size respectively
2) add/remove elements

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the screenshot was taken from MMT app. They're using this feature in their app. I believe, they might have developed a separate control to handle this thing, where they can only pass few arguments like image to show (people), count etc.

You can also develop such kind of UI with following way:

- Create a custom view, take a `UICollectionView` inside it, take argument of image to show and number of rows count, fixed the cell size in layouts. Add a method which will reloads UI (inside logic: reloading `UICollectionView`) to refresh content when user taps on [ + ] or [ - ] button. Why, we're not taking `UIScrollView`, with it we can't reuse contents. <sup>I believe this step will need you to create everything programmatically.</sup>
- When user taps on [ + ], you should increase width of our custom view, inside 
  you should override [`layoutSubview` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called) to update frame of `UICollectionView` as well. <sup>You may require to refresh(reload) cells inside `UICollectionView`.</sup>
- Do reverse when user taps [ - ].
- You may require to set some logic so user can't add more/less numbers when selection.

This is just an idea, you may require to check each cases which the reference app has having.