# swift 4 - why doesn't UIButton move when told to?

Tags: ios, swift4

Why wouldn't a UIButton move when I call:

```
myButton.frame.origin.x = 100
```

I am calling it from within the viewDidLayoutSubviews() function, the function is called because an annotation is created on a map, though the button is in a view which isn't really related to the map.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737164/whats-exactly-viewdidlayoutsubviews

Comment: You don't move UIButton.frame but an instance of UIButton class,

Comment: Maybe it has moved, but you just don't realise it because it moves before you render the screen

Comment: Are you using autolayout?  If so, any change to the frame will be overridden when autolayout computes the layout.  You need to modify the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLayoutSubviews() Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.

So this is our chance to make changes to view after it has laid out it's subviews, but before it is visible on screen.

Any changes that depending on bounds has to be done, we can do here and not in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear.

[What's exactly viewDidLayoutSubviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737164/whats-exactly-viewdidlayoutsubviews)