# When the tableView height is true height

Tags: ios, swift

Thanks to help.

I use the Nib to deal with the TablViewCell, but when I try to draw graphics in cell.contentView, I can not get the true height in awakeFormNib(), so how can I get the true height to draw the correct graphics.

The cell is a dynamic cell and I use the UITableViewCell + FDTemplateLayoutCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this in cell subclass and get the true height:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Get frame: self.contentView.frame
}
```

And load nib cell. First, register nib:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCellNibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuseIdentifier"];
```

Load nib in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
id cell  = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuseIdentifier"];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellNibName" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]){
            cell =  currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Believe you can convert it to Swift.

[When is layoutSubviews called?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330162/6279975)

Comment: When I use Nib, I drag the Cell Size different size with iPhone, and when I run the demo in phone, the first size is nib cell size, not phone size , even in layoutSubviews fund ,so how can I set the true size in nib.

Comment: @Eggplant How you initialize the Cell?

Comment: register the Nib.

Comment: I make a mistake,When I use the func layoutSubview(), I draw a line use the subView frame. Cell.contentView.frame is correct, but subview frame is wrong.