# UIButton subview is offset in subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton subclass intended to show a selected state of a button. The selected state simply places a thick black line at the bottom of the button view and when unselected it hides the black line. However, when using this in a UIButton subclass, the black line view is offset. I have tried playing around with insets, but I don't think that is the problem. Here is my subclass:

```
class TabButton: UIButton {

    private var height:CGFloat = 5
    private var selectedIndicator:UIView?

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet { 
            selectedIndicator?.isHidden = !isSelected 
        }
    }

    fileprivate func initializeSelector(_ frame: CGRect) {
        selectedIndicator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - height, width: frame.size.width, height: height))
        selectedIndicator?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black 
        self.addSubview(selectedIndicator!)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initializeSelector(self.frame)
    }
}
```

The desired button should look like this:

[image]

But instead it looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in layoutSubviews you get the final frame:

```
override layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    selectedIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - height, width: frame.size.width, height: height)
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. By calling `initializeSelector()` inside `layoutSubviews` you'll end up having multiple(as many as `layoutSubviews` is called) black views as the subview of button since `initializeSelector` inserts a new black `UIView` as subview.

Comment: You are right my fault, thank you ;) I was writing from mobile app and I didn’t notice that the method is adding the view. I was sure he was adding the view in awake from nib.

Answer (score 1):

The frame of the `selectedIndicator` is set only once when `initializeSelector` is called. When the button changes its frame, it does **not** change the frame of subviews, you need to manually update the frame of `selectedIndicator`.

To do so, you need to override [`layoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) method of `UIView`.

```
override layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    selectedIndicator?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - height, width: frame.size.width, height: height)
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/) answer to know when `layoutSubviews()` is called.