# IBDesignable ButtonView right border overlapping on orientation change (Landscape)

Tags: ios, swift, overlapping, orientation-changes, ibdesignable

I have a problem managing my `UITableView` with `IBDesignable ButtonView` and orientation. Basically, the problem happens when I switch to landscape, right border of customView inside `UITableViewCell` is overlapping. This is only happening when I change the orientation to landscape. It should be able to show right border properly inside the cell.

Anyone have any ideas on this problem? I included a image on how my layout is organized and the behavior:

[In `Portrait`, working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lgw2.png)

[In `Landscape`, right border overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jndNq.png)

To add more details, each `ButtonView` has boolean defined as `User Defined Runtime Attributes` in `Storyboard`, which is true for first 2 buttons.

Here is the `IBDesignable ButtonView` implementation

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ButtonView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var title: String? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = title
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var hasRightBorder: Bool = false

    @IBInspectable var disabledColor: UIColor = Colors.lightGray
    @IBInspectable var enabledColor: UIColor = Colors.primary
    @IBInspectable var iconSize: CGFloat = 16.0 {
        didSet {
            imageView.addConstraints(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
        }
    }
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    var titleLabel = UILabel()
    var button = UIButton(type: .custom)

    var isEnabled = true {
        didSet {
            if isEnabled {
                imageView.tintColor = enabledColor
                titleLabel.textColor = enabledColor
            } else {
                imageView.tintColor = disabledColor
                titleLabel.textColor = disabledColor
            }

            button.isEnabled = isEnabled
        }
    }

    var buttonClosure: (() ->Void)?

    // MARK: - Initializers
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupView()
    }

    // MARK: - View lifecycle
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if hasRightBorder {
            layer.addBorder(edge: .right, color: Colors.lightGray, thickness: 1.0)
        } else {
            layer.addBorder(edge: .right, color: UIColor.clear, thickness: 0.0)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Actions
    @objc fileprivate func buttonTapped() {
        buttonClosure?()
    }

    // MARK: - Private API
    fileprivate func setupView() {
        imageView.tintColor = enabledColor
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5.0).isActive = true
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        titleLabel.textColor = Colors.primary
        titleLabel.font = FontBook.regular.of(size: .extraSmall)
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5.0).isActive = true
        titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(button)
        button.fillSuperview(with: -10.0)
    }

}
```

addBorder implementation

```
extension CALayer {

    func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {
        let border = CALayer();

        switch edge {
        case UIRectEdge.top:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.frame.height - thickness, width:self.frame.width, height:thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: thickness, height: self.frame.height)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x:self.frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height:self.frame.height)
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;

        addSublayer(border)
    }

}
```

[Here is how it looks in `Storyboard`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Jio.png)

Comment: Looks like `layoutSubviews` adds the right border but never removes the old one. So the portrait border is visible in landscape. Plus you are piling up borders. Of course a lot depends on what `addBorder` does. But you didn’t snow that code.

Comment: @matt, how can I remove the old one? can you please suggest a solution? thanks

Comment: No, you didn’t show how you’re adding it! But remember layout can happen hundreds of times. You are running that code over and over.

Comment: I've added `addBorder ` implementation

Comment: Yes, that confirms what I said.

Comment: Can you please propose a solution?

Comment: Rewrite that method so it removes the sublayer it previously added.

Comment: @matt I resolve the issue. thanks for the pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue using different approach. I came to know by looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called) that many things including rotating a device calls `layoutSubview`. that's why a border was repeating. I'm posting my solution incase someone facing the same issue.

First, instead of defining a boolean `hasRightBorder`, I created a `border` of width 1 inside [`Storyboard`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFP2C.png)

Then, I define a `UIView` inside `ButtonView` class, set the width and frame heightened add it to the view. Worked like charm :)

```
@IBDesignable
class ButtonView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }

    //Add the rightBorder support
    @IBInspectable var border: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            view.addConstraints(width: border, height: frame.size.height)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Initializers
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupView()
    }

    //view to add right border
    var view = UIView()

    // MARK: - Private API
    fileprivate func setupView() {

        //Set the color & add it to view
        view.backgroundColor = Colors.lightGray
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(view)

        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    }

}
```